# Identify this 1980 vintage Canon calculator "all-in-one" IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, calculator

I am attempting to reverse-engineer a Canon "P10-D II" desktop calculator (assembled circa 1980).

The main PCB is single-layer which makes life easier apart from the fact that I cannot find any information at all on the main IC.  It's a 40-pin DIP of 0.1" pitch.

The part number appears to be `M58881P` and there is a further code of `9Z90` which I assume is a factory or batch code (it's definitely not a date code, this entire unit was built in April 1980 and has had no modification since then).  I suppose it is possible that this isn't a proper part number at all and might be a proprietary SKU or something that only made sense to Canon or the chip-maker at the time).

The small logo to the left of the part number looks lot like the logo of the [Misubishi Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitsubishi).

I think that this is not a "CPU" as such because it has no external RAM, and also has application-specific hardware built-in, such as DC-DC converter control hardware to provide the high voltages required to run the VFD.

I cannot find schematics for any part of this machine, even photographs of the internals are very scarce and usually too small to be helpful.

### Question

Can you help me to find out more about this chip?  Ideally I'd like to get hold of at least a pin-out diagram to make the rest of the reverse-engineering task a bit simpler.

(I'll add some more info as I get further along with tracing out the PCB signals...)

[image]

Comment: Agree it looks like the Mitsubishi logo.   The "P" may mean "programmable" i.e. just copying this circuit isn't going to get you there - You need to be able to upload a program to it.   A CPU doesn't require external RAM if it's built-into the chip.   This is pretty common nowadays (to have a whole "SOC" or "System On Chip").  In 1980 it woulda been a more application-specific thing.

Comment: Probably  a custom chip. You better reverse the other parts of the PCB and you will be able to identify the interfaces (display, keyboard). Then you can replace the chip with an MCU of your choice to perform similar operations.

Comment: Found a [pinout for Mitsubishi M58872P](https://www.rskey.org/~mwsebastian/calcwebpg/mitsubishi.htm#m58872p) calculator chip. Maybe the pinout is similar...

Comment: Also https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf/275587/Mitsubishi/M58481P/1 is the M58481P datasheet so this is another member of an established range of ICs. I suspect P is Plastic (epoxy) rather than Ceramic package. Search "Mitsubishi IC Databook" and look at a few from the 1980s, you may get lucky

Comment: Unrelated to your question I would not advise to connect a ribbon cable like that without strain relief. The joints will very easily break.